# Python truncating international string

Tags: python, string, encoding, apple-push-notifications

I've been trying to debug this for far too long, and I obviously have no idea what I'm doing, so hopefully someone can help. I'm not even sure what I should be asking, but here it goes:

I'm trying to send Apple Push Notifications, and they have a payload size limit of 256 bytes. So subtract some overhead stuff, and I'm left with about 100 english characters of main message content.

So if a message is longer than the max, I truncate it:

```
MAX_PUSH_LENGTH = 100
body = (body[:MAX_PUSH_LENGTH]) if len(body) > MAX_PUSH_LENGTH else body
```

So that's fine and dandy, and no matter how long of a message I have (in english), the push notification sends successfully. However, now I have an Arabic string:

```
str = "هيك بنكون 
عيش بجنون تون تون تون هيك بنكون 
عيش بجنون تون تون تون 
أوكي أ"

>>> print len(str)
109
```

So that should truncate. But, I always get an invalid payload size error! Curious, I kept lowering the MAX_PUSH_LENGTH threshold to see what it would take for it to succeed, and it's not until I set the limit to around 60 that the push notification succeeded.

I'm not exactly sure if this has something to do with the byte size of languages other than english. It is my understanding that an English character takes one byte, so does an Arabic character take 2 bytes? Might this have something to do with it?

Also, the string is JSON encoded before it is sent off, so it ends up looking something like this: `\u0647\u064a\u0643 \u0628\u0646\u0643\u0648\u0646 \n\u0639\u064a\u0634 ...` Could it be that it is being interpreted as a raw string, and just u0647 is 5 bytes?

What should I be doing here? Are there any obvious errors or am I not asking the right question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cut to bytes length, so you need first to `.encode('utf-8')` your string, and then cut it at a code point boundary.

In UTF-8, ASCII (`<= 127`) are 1-byte. [Bytes with two or more most significant bits set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) (`>= 192`) are character-starting bytes; the number of bytes that follow is determined by the number of most significant bits set. Anything else is continuation bytes.

A problem may arise if you cut the multi-byte sequence in the middle; if a character did not fit, it should be cut completely, up to the starting byte.

Here's some working code:

```
LENGTH_BY_PREFIX = [
  (0xC0, 2), # first byte mask, total codepoint length
  (0xE0, 3), 
  (0xF0, 4),
  (0xF8, 5),
  (0xFC, 6),
]

def codepoint_length(first_byte):
    if first_byte < 128:
        return 1 # ASCII
    for mask, length in LENGTH_BY_PREFIX:
        if first_byte & mask == mask:
            return length
    assert False, 'Invalid byte %r' % first_byte

def cut_to_bytes_length(unicode_text, byte_limit):
    utf8_bytes = unicode_text.encode('UTF-8')
    cut_index = 0
    while cut_index < len(utf8_bytes):
        step = codepoint_length(ord(utf8_bytes[cut_index]))
        if cut_index + step > byte_limit:
            # can't go a whole codepoint further, time to cut
            return utf8_bytes[:cut_index]
        else:
            cut_index += step
    # length limit is longer than our bytes strung, so no cutting
    return utf8_bytes
```

Now test. If `.decode()` succeeds, we have made a correct cut.

```
unicode_text = u"هيك بنكون" # note that the literal here is Unicode

print cut_to_bytes_length(unicode_text, 100).decode('UTF-8')
print cut_to_bytes_length(unicode_text, 10).decode('UTF-8')
print cut_to_bytes_length(unicode_text, 5).decode('UTF-8')
print cut_to_bytes_length(unicode_text, 4).decode('UTF-8')
print cut_to_bytes_length(unicode_text, 3).decode('UTF-8')
print cut_to_bytes_length(unicode_text, 2).decode('UTF-8')

# This returns empty strings, because an Arabic letter
# requires at least 2 bytes to represent in UTF-8.
print cut_to_bytes_length(unicode_text, 1).decode('UTF-8')
```

You can test that the code works with ASCII as well.

Comment: Awesome code snippets, thanks. Out of curiosity, what would happen if I were to cut a multi-byte sequence in the middle? Would it not be able to be decoded?

Comment: Your code doesn't always work. Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727977/truncating-string-to-byte-length-in-python

Comment: In UTF-8, never split before a byte with 10xxxxxx as the bit pattern.  These are always intermediate bytes of a multibyte UTF-8 sequence.  That should simplify your algorithm.

Comment: Do we have 6 byte characters?

Comment: @lfk: No, the longest UTF-8 sequence is 4 bytes, though it could, it principle, extend indefinitely. The highest Unicode code point is 10FFFF, so it takes 3 bytes, but nobody has 3-byte machines, so the widest "raw" Unicode representation in e.g. CPython is 32 bit.

Comment: Your code has two problems: `ord` needs to be removed since it's bytes already, and order of elements in `LENGTH_BY_PREFIX` needs to be reversed

Answer (score 12):

If you have a python unicode value and you want to truncate, the following is a very short, general, and efficient way to do it in Python.

```
def truncate_unicode_to_byte_limit(src, byte_limit, encoding='utf-8'):
    '''
    truncate a unicode value to fit within byte_limit when encoded in encoding

    src: a unicode
    byte_limit: a non-negative integer
    encoding: a text encoding

    returns a unicode prefix of src guaranteed to fit within byte_limit when
    encoded as encoding.
    '''
    return src.encode(encoding)[:byte_limit].decode(encoding, 'ignore')
```

So for example:

```
s = u"""
    هيك بنكون
    ascii
    عيش بجنون تون تون تون هيك بنكون
    عيش بجنون تون تون تون
    أوكي أ
"""

b = truncate_unicode_to_byte_limit(s, 73)
print len(b.encode('utf-8')), b
```

produces output:

```
73 
    هيك بنكون
    ascii
    عيش بجنون تون تون تو
```

Comment: I'v not test it yet, but it seems most elegant answer to me.

Answer (score 4):

For a unicode string `s`, you would need to use something like `len(s.encode('utf-8'))` to get its length in bytes. `len(s)` just returns the number of (unencoded) characters.

**Update:**
After further research I discovered that Python has support for incremental encoding which makes it possible to write a reasonably fast function to trim-off excess characters while avoiding the corruption of any multi-byte encoding sequences within the string. Here's example code using it for this task:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import encodings
_incr_encoder = encodings.search_function('utf8').incrementalencoder()

def utf8_byte_truncate(text, max_bytes):
    """ truncate utf-8 text string to no more than max_bytes long """
    byte_len = 0
    _incr_encoder.reset()
    for index,ch in enumerate(text):
        byte_len += len(_incr_encoder.encode(ch))
        if byte_len > max_bytes:
            break
    else:
        return text
    return text[:index]

s = u"""
    هيك بنكون
    ascii
    عيش بجنون تون تون تون هيك بنكون
    عيش بجنون تون تون تون
    أوكي أ
"""

print 'initial string:'
print s.encode('utf-8')
print "{} chars, {} bytes".format(len(s), len(s.encode('utf-8')))
print
s2 = utf8_byte_truncate(s, 74)  # trim string
print 'after truncation to no more than 74 bytes:'
# following will raise encoding error exception on any improper truncations
print s2.encode('utf-8')
print "{} chars, {} bytes".format(len(s2), len(s2.encode('utf-8')))
```

Output:

```
initial string:

    هيك بنكون
    ascii
    عيش بجنون تون تون تون هيك بنكون
    عيش بجنون تون تون تون
    أوكي أ

98 chars, 153 bytes

after truncation to no more than 74 bytes:

    هيك بنكون
    ascii
    عيش بجنون تون تون تو
49 chars, 73 bytes
```

Comment: Very weird. I tried that earlier but I got an error while encoding, but I just tried it again with no errors. So once its encoded in UTF8, can I treat it like a string and truncate it?

Comment: @mohabitar: Not directly, but there's likely a better way to do it than what I've shown.

Comment: @mohabitar: I've revised the code so that it does it incrementally in a much smarter way. It would be interesting to see how it compared, speed-wise to 9000's answer...

Comment: I'm curious what you think of the answers you got and whether either of the was good enough for you to accept.

Comment: Sure they were good..though looking through my logs yesterday I saw there was an exception thrown using the code from the answer by 9000, so I'm trying to replicate that and figure out what the exact string was, so I can try out your solution to see if it works better. I can't accept an answer till I know it works..there's no rush to get your 15 or so points ;)

Comment: I've tracked down what the troublemaker was. It's emoji. And neither your code nor 9000's code work properly in that case. Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727977/truncating-string-to-byte-length-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Using the [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738452/235698) I posted on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13727977/235698), this will encode a Unicode string at UTF-8 and truncate only whole UTF-8 sequences to arrive at an encoding length less than or equal to a maximum length:

```
s = u"""
    هيك بنكون
    ascii
    عيش بجنون تون تون تون هيك بنكون
    عيش بجنون تون تون تون
    أوكي أ
"""

def utf8_lead_byte(b):
    '''A UTF-8 intermediate byte starts with the bits 10xxxxxx.'''
    return (ord(b) & 0xC0) != 0x80

def utf8_byte_truncate(text,max_bytes):
    '''If text[max_bytes] is not a lead byte, back up until a lead byte is
    found and truncate before that character.'''
    utf8 = text.encode('utf8')
    if len(utf8) <= max_bytes:
        return utf8
    i = max_bytes
    while i > 0 and not utf8_lead_byte(utf8[i]):
        i -= 1
    return utf8[:i]

b = utf8_byte_truncate(s,74)
print len(b),b.decode('utf8')
```

#### Output

```
73 
    هيك بنكون
    ascii
    عيش بجنون تون تون تو
```