# Truncating string to byte length in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a function here to truncate a given string to a given byte length:

```
LENGTH_BY_PREFIX = [
  (0xC0, 2), # first byte mask, total codepoint length
  (0xE0, 3), 
  (0xF0, 4),
  (0xF8, 5),
  (0xFC, 6),
]

def codepoint_length(first_byte):
    if first_byte < 128:
        return 1 # ASCII
    for mask, length in LENGTH_BY_PREFIX:
        if first_byte & mask == mask:
            return length
    assert False, 'Invalid byte %r' % first_byte

def cut_string_to_bytes_length(unicode_text, byte_limit):
    utf8_bytes = unicode_text.encode('UTF-8')
    cut_index = 0
    while cut_index < len(utf8_bytes):
        step = codepoint_length(ord(utf8_bytes[cut_index]))
        if cut_index + step > byte_limit:
            # can't go a whole codepoint further, time to cut
            return utf8_bytes[:cut_index]
        else:
            cut_index += step
    # length limit is longer than our bytes strung, so no cutting
    return utf8_bytes
```

This seemed to work fine until the question of Emoji was introduced:

```
string = u"\ud83d\ude14"
trunc = cut_string_to_bytes_length(string, 100)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 5, in cut_string_to_bytes_length
  File "<console>", line 7, in codepoint_length
AssertionError: Invalid byte 152
```

Can anyone explain exactly what is going on here, and what a possible solution is?

**Edit:** I have another code snippet here that doesn't throw an exception, but has weird behavior sometimes:

```
import encodings
_incr_encoder = encodings.search_function('utf8').incrementalencoder()

def utf8_byte_truncate(text, max_bytes):
    """ truncate utf-8 text string to no more than max_bytes long """
    byte_len = 0
    _incr_encoder.reset()
    for index,ch in enumerate(text):
        byte_len += len(_incr_encoder.encode(ch))
        if byte_len > max_bytes:
            break
    else:
        return text
    return text[:index]

>>> string = u"\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14" 
>>> print string
(prints a set of 5 Apple Emoji...)
>>> len(string)
10
>>> trunc = utf8_byte_truncate(string, 4)
>>> print trunc
???
>>> len(trunc)
1
```

So with this second example, I have a string of 10 bytes, truncate it to 4, but something weird happens, and the result is a string of size 1 byte.

Comment: In the second example, your string is composed of 20 bytes, not 10. For some reason the utf-8 incremental encoder says the first two characters require 3 bytes each, so after the first one there isn't enough room for another 3 byte one since you're telling it to truncating to no more than 4 bytes, so it only returns a string 1 character (not bytes) long. Supposedly this character took 3 of the 4 bytes.

Comment: You are processing a Unicode string, not bytes, and that string contains two UTF-16 surrogates that you are trying to process as UTF-8 bytes.  Python 3.3 makes this easier by avoiding surrogates.  It might help if we knew what higher level problem you were trying to solve, because processing strings as encoded bytes usually isn't the way to go.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: See [Python truncating international string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13665001/355230) for the higher level problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a number f is such that `f & 0xF0 == 0xF0`, then it is also the case that `f & 0xC0 == 0xC0` because 0xF0 has all the bits that 0xC0 has, and then some.  That is, among other problems your `codepoint_length()` function will return a step of 2 when it should be 4.  If you reverse your LENGTH_BY_PREFIX list, the function works ok with the first example.

```
LENGTH_BY_PREFIX = [
  (0xFC, 6),
  (0xF8, 5),
  (0xF0, 4),
  (0xE0, 3), 
  (0xC0, 2), # first byte mask, total codepoint length
]
```

Answer (score 13):

The algorithm is wrong as @jwpat7 indicated.  A simpler algorithm is the following, but note some perceived single characters (called *graphemes*) are made up of more than one Unicode code point such as ‍‍‍.  This doesn't attempt to maintain graphemes.

```
# NOTE: This is Python 2 to match OP's code

# s = u'\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14'
# Same as above
s = u'\U0001f614' * 5   # Unicode character U+1F614

def utf8_lead_byte(b):
    '''A UTF-8 intermediate byte starts with the bits 10xxxxxx.'''

    # (b & 0xC0) != 0x80 # Python 3 no need for ord()
    return (ord(b) & 0xC0) != 0x80

def utf8_byte_truncate(text, max_bytes):
    '''If text[max_bytes] is not a lead byte, back up until a lead byte is
    found and truncate before that character.'''
    utf8 = text.encode('utf8')
    if len(utf8) <= max_bytes:
        return utf8
    i = max_bytes
    while i > 0 and not utf8_lead_byte(utf8[i]):
        i -= 1
    return utf8[:i]

# test for various max_bytes:
for m in range(len(s.encode('utf8'))+1):
    b = utf8_byte_truncate(s,m)
    print m,len(b),b.decode('utf8')
```

###Output

```
0 0 
1 0 
2 0 
3 0 
4 4 
5 4 
6 4 
7 4 
8 8 
9 8 
10 8 
11 8 
12 12 
13 12 
14 12 
15 12 
16 16 
17 16 
18 16 
19 16 
20 20
```

Comment: Why are you using ord on a byte? It was failing here on Python 3, I removed ord and works fine

Comment: @Ifk Because this is Python 2 code (note the print syntax). Python 3 is not backward compatible. In Python 2 indexing a string returns a string, and you can't bitwise-AND a string and and int.  In Python 3, indexing a byte string returns an integer, so there would be no need for ord().

Answer (score 4):

Version of Mark's code for Python 3:

```
# s = u'\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14\ud83d\ude14'
# Same as above
s = u'\U0001f614' * 5   # Unicode character U+1F614

def utf8_lead_byte(b):
    '''A UTF-8 intermediate byte starts with the bits 10xxxxxx.'''
    return (b & 0xC0) != 0x80

def utf8_byte_truncate(text, max_bytes):
    '''If text[max_bytes] is not a lead byte, back up until a lead byte is
    found and truncate before that character.'''
    utf8 = text.encode('utf8')
    if len(utf8) <= max_bytes:
        return utf8
    i = max_bytes
    while i > 0 and not utf8_lead_byte(utf8[i]):
        i -= 1
    return utf8[:i]

# test for various max_bytes:
for m in range(len(s.encode('utf8'))+1):
    b = utf8_byte_truncate(s,m)
    print(m,len(b),b.decode('utf8'))
```

EDIT: this is the original code by Mark Tolonen adapted for python3. The previous code was wrong. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Why not just remove `ord`  from `utf8_lead_byte`? `utf8[i]` is the byte which is what we want, isn't it?

Comment: @Ifk This code is incorrect for Python 3.  In my original code porting to Python 3 would mean removing `ord()` (indexed byte strings return `int` in Python 3) and switching to `print()` vs. `print`.  This code doesn't work.  The `join` is wrong as it maps UTF-8 bytes to Unicode characters and `staticmethod` isn't applied to functions.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen - Code snippet now fixed and tested. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3):

(python3) and a lot simpler than previous answers:

```
cut_index = len(unicode_text.encode('utf8', errors="replace")[:max_length_byte].decode('utf8', errors="ignore"))
unicode_text[:cut_index]
```

The idea is to cut the encoded string at the byte length, then decode with ignoring errors (possibly removing a character that was broken by cutting).

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer by `dreamflasher`

this will cut the filename in the middle and insert `...` as ellipsis chars

example result: `123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456...456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789`

```py
def cut_filename(filename):
    # limit filename length to 255 bytes
    max_filename_length = 255
    filename_bytes = filename.encode("utf8")
    if len(filename_bytes) > max_filename_length:
        cut_bytes = filename_bytes[:max_filename_length]
        filename_new_size = len(cut_bytes.decode("utf8", errors="ignore"))
        cut_idx = int(filename_new_size / 2) - 1
        filename = filename[:cut_idx] + "..." + filename[(-1 * cut_idx):]
    return filename
```

test

```py
filename_base = "1234567890" * 30 # 300 bytes
filename_base = "123456789Ö" * 30
filename_base = "123Ä56789Ö" * 30
filename_base = "oooo" + ("123Ä56789Ö" * 30)
filename_list = []
for i in range(255, 260):
    filename_list.append(filename_base[:i])

for filename in filename_list:
    filename_2 = cut_filename(filename)
    print(len(filename.encode("utf8")), len(filename_2.encode("utf8")), filename_2)
    print()
```