# Truncate a string to a specific number of bytes in Python

Tags: python, string

How can I truncate a string to be no longer than 50 bytes?

```
a = 'asdfzx안녕하세요awelkjawletjawetr방갑습니다.dlgawklejtwgasdgsdfgd
sdfasdfsdafa궁금해요rewgargasregawergedrhsedhesrdhrthdrfjydjdrktydjdyj'
max = 50byte
a = max(a)
```

Comment: Please be more clear. Do you want the first 50 characters in the given string? Note that it is bad form to talk about *bytes* in *text*: that became outdated with the advent of Unicode and even before that. A character may take more than one byte.

Comment: To give you a correct answer we need to know what version of Python you are using: Python 2.x or Python 3.x?

Comment: see also [Truncating string to byte length in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727977/truncating-string-to-byte-length-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `getsizeof()` to get the size and then put it in a if statement to check.`getsizeof()` returns the size of an object in bytes.Hope my example gives you an idea :

```
from sys import getsizeof
a = '4200547985984359347509gbrtbhrtbrtbargrefefwefwef'
b =  'hello'
if getsizeof(a.encode('ascii')) > 50 :
    print("Error:a")
if getsizeof(b.encode('ascii')) > 50 :
    print("Error:b")
```

Comment: sorry my english is bad .   not to 50 charaters, i want to 50 byte.

Comment: @PotemPotem oh ,look at my updated answer,this is what you might be looking for. :)

Comment: @Achilles That won't works, the in-memory representation size of python objects is not the same as the size the asker want to know: `getsizeof('a'.encode('ascii')) == 34`.

Comment: It is  weird... I know one english charater is 1byte. and I know one korea charater is 2byte...

Comment: @PotemPotem That's not the case with all encodings. Speaking of the in-memory representation, the cpython implementation of strings has quite an overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (to truncate to 10 bytes):

```
s = "asdfzx안녕하세요awelkjawletjawetr방갑습니"
s.encode('utf-8')[:10].decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

Comment: no, this can produce invalid utf8 characters

Answer (score 1):

You could just use slicing if you are using a one character per byte encoding:

```
a = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'

a[:50]
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

Note that would only makes sense if you are writing this somewhere. If the size of the python object representation makes more sense in your use-case, the answer of @Achilles should works.