# Efficient way to cut a (UTF-8) string in Python to a given maximal byte length

Tags: python, string, memory, unicode

For storage in a given Oracle table (whose field lengths are defined in bytes) I need to cut strings beforehand in Python 3 to a maximal length *in Bytes*, although the strings can contain UTF-8 characters.

My solution is to concatenate the result string character by character from the original string and check when the result string exceeds the length limit:

```
def cut_str_to_bytes(s, max_bytes):
    """
    Ensure that a string has not more than max_bytes bytes
    :param s: The string (utf-8 encoded)
    :param max_bytes: Maximal number of bytes
    :return: The cut string
    """
    def len_as_bytes(s):
        return len(s.encode(errors='replace'))

    if len_as_bytes(s) <= max_bytes:
        return s

    res = ""
    for c in s:
        old = res
        res += c
        if len_as_bytes(res) > max_bytes:
            res = old
            break
    return res
```

This is obviously rather slow. ***What is an efficient way to do this?***

ps: I saw [Truncate a string to a specific number of bytes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949704/truncate-a-string-to-a-specific-number-of-bytes-in-python), but their solution to use `sys.getsizeof()` does not give the number of bytes of the string characters, but rather the size of the whole string object (Python need some bytes to manage the string object), so that does not really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid to cut a UTF-8 string anywhere except in the middle of a multibyte character. So, if you want the longest UTF-8 string within a maximum byte length, what you need is to first take the max bytes and then reduce it as long as it has an unfinished character at the end.

Compared to your solution, which has O(n) complexity, because it goes character-by-character, this one just removes up to 3 bytes from the end (because a UTF-8 character is never longer than 4 bytes).

[RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) specifies these as valid UTF-8 byte sequences:

```
Char. number range  |        UTF-8 octet sequence
      (hexadecimal)    |              (binary)
   --------------------+---------------------------------------------
   0000 0000-0000 007F | 0xxxxxxx
   0000 0080-0000 07FF | 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
   0000 0800-0000 FFFF | 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
   0001 0000-0010 FFFF | 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

So, the simplest way to go with a valid UTF-8 stream:

- if the last character is `0xxxxxxx`, all is fine
- otherwise, find the location of a `11xxxxxx` within the last 4 bytes to see whether you have a complete character, based on the table above

Therefore, this should work:

```
def cut_str_to_bytes(s, max_bytes):
    # cut it twice to avoid encoding potentially GBs of `s` just to get e.g. 10 bytes?
    b = s[:max_bytes].encode('utf-8')[:max_bytes]

    if b[-1] & 0b10000000:
        last_11xxxxxx_index = [i for i in range(-1, -5, -1)
                               if b[i] & 0b11000000 == 0b11000000][0]
        # note that last_11xxxxxx_index is negative

        last_11xxxxxx = b[last_11xxxxxx_index]
        if not last_11xxxxxx & 0b00100000:
            last_char_length = 2
        elif not last_11xxxxxx & 0b0010000:
            last_char_length = 3
        elif not last_11xxxxxx & 0b0001000:
            last_char_length = 4

        if last_char_length > -last_11xxxxxx_index:
            # remove the incomplete character
            b = b[:last_11xxxxxx_index]

    return b.decode('utf-8')
```

Alternatively, you may try decoding the last bytes, rather than doing the low-level stuff, but I'm not sure the code would be simpler that way...

**Note:** The function shown here works for strings which are longer than two characters. A version which also covers the edge cases of shorter strings can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/halloleo/unicut/blob/master/truncate.py).

Comment: Thanks @zvone! Just wrote some tests for your function and it works **perfectly**! Really great answer!

Comment: *Side note:* I don't think it is appropriate to mark the question-answer set here as a duplicate of [Truncating string to byte length in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727977/truncating-string-to-byte-length-in-python): Although the idea over there is the same the code snippets in all the answers do not lead to a working function answering my question. - However I do not know how to initiate a review process. :-(

Comment: Actually @zvone, through further testing I found out that your function sometimes fails to handle two-byte encoded Unicode characters (like '\x80'): The looking-back by `-5` gives obviously an `IndexError`.

Comment: @halloleo It does not work on too short strings, true. It's a special case which needs to be handled.

Comment: I have put a version covering the edge cases [on GitHub](https://github.com/halloleo/unicut/blob/master/truncate.py). - Will add it to your answer.