# Truncating a UTF-16 string

Tags: python, unicode, utf-16

I maintain a Python library which validates and prepares input for a downstream Java service. As such, the pre-validation within the library needs to be consistent with this downstream service. A pain point here has been calculating string length for certain Unicode strings.

Python counts characters to determine the length of a string, while Java counts code units (i.e. UTF-16 surrogate pairs). Usually these calculations are the same, but beyond the Basic Multilingual Plane these can differ. For example, the string "wink " would have length 6 in Python and length 7 in Java (2 for the emoji + 5 for the other characters).

To replicate Java's length calculation methodology, therefore, we need to encode as UTF-16 and then divide by 2:

```
field_value = "wink "    
len(field_value.encode("utf-16-le")) // 2
```

However, if I want to *truncate* an input string to the maximum permitted character limit based on a UTF-16 codepair methodology this is more challenging. Converting to UTF-16 then slicing is overzealous since not ALL the characters will be outside of the BMP:

```
field_value = "wink "  
field_value.encode("utf-16-le")[:LIMIT].decode("utf-16-le", "ignore")
```

**What would be an efficient way in Python to truncate a Unicode string (containing BMP + post-BMP characters) in line with this character weighting?**

Comment: You can't know how large a character in the middle of the string is in advance.

Comment: FYI code points are not the same as graphemes. See combining characters. In particular, "zalgo text" stacks a ton of combining characters into a single grapheme. Ask yourself what the limit is actually for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to truncate at a valid codepoint in the string.  It works by testing that a too long string doesn't truncate in the middle of a surrogate pair.  It's based on [this similar answer of mine for truncating UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738452/235698).  Note this does not handle graphemes.  You can use `unicodedata.category()` if needed to test for truncating modifiers.

```py
s = 'A  short  test'

def utf16_trailing_surrogate(b):
    '''The high byte of a UTF-16 trailing surrogate starts with the bits 110111xx.'''
    return (b & 0b1111_1100) == 0b1101_1100

def utf16_byte_truncate(text, max_bytes):
    '''If text[max_bytes:max_bytes+1] is a trailing surrogate, back up two bytes and truncate.
    '''
    i = max_bytes - max_bytes % 2  # make even
    utf16 = text.encode('utf-16le')
    if len(utf16) <= i: # does it fit
        return utf16
    if utf16_trailing_surrogate(utf16[i+1]):
        i -= 2
    return utf16[:i]

# test for various max_bytes:
for m in range(len(s.encode('utf-16le'))+1):
    b = utf16_byte_truncate(s,m)
    print(f'{m:2} {len(b):2} {b.decode("utf-16le")!r}')
```

Output:

```
 0  0 ''
 1  0 ''
 2  2 'A'
 3  2 'A'
 4  4 'A '
 5  4 'A '
 6  4 'A '
 7  4 'A '
 8  8 'A '
 9  8 'A '
10 10 'A  '
11 10 'A  '
12 12 'A  s'
13 12 'A  s'
14 14 'A  sh'
15 14 'A  sh'
16 16 'A  sho'
17 16 'A  sho'
18 18 'A  shor'
19 18 'A  shor'
20 20 'A  short'
21 20 'A  short'
22 22 'A  short '
23 22 'A  short '
24 22 'A  short '
25 22 'A  short '
26 26 'A  short '
27 26 'A  short '
28 26 'A  short '
29 26 'A  short '
30 30 'A  short '
31 30 'A  short '
32 32 'A  short  '
33 32 'A  short  '
34 34 'A  short  t'
35 34 'A  short  t'
36 36 'A  short  te'
37 36 'A  short  te'
38 38 'A  short  tes'
39 38 'A  short  tes'
40 40 'A  short  test'
```